# get a list of instances on ec2 without termination protection?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I want to get a list of instances on ec2 without termination protection.
Before I code something to do this, is there something hidden in the aws cli for this ?

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me from the docs and my testing that you are looking for:

```
#aws ec2 describe-instance-attribute --instance-id <instanceid> --attribute disableApiTermination
```

This returns

`<instanceid>
DISABLEAPITERMINATION   True`

If termination protection is on. The documentation states, "If the value is true, you can't terminate the instance through the Amazon EC2 console, CLI, or API; otherwise, you can."

And you can modify the parameter with modify-instance-attribute. So...

```
#aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --no-disable-api-termination --instance-id <instanceid>
```

or

```
#aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --disable-api-termination --instance-id <instanceid>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a script that will list the termination protection for all instances in all regions. It requires the AWS CLI to be installed and in the `$PATH`:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

for region in $(aws ec2 describe-regions | grep RegionName | cut -d '"' -f 4 | sort); do
    echo $region
    for instance in $(aws ec2 describe-instances --region $region | grep InstanceId | cut -d '"' -f 4 | sort); do
        echo -n $instance
        aws ec2 describe-instance-attribute --region $region --instance-id $instance --attribute disableApiTermination | grep Value | cut -d : -f 2
    done
done
```

If you're just working on one region, and the CLI is already configured for that region, you can simplify it and speed it up a bit:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

for instance in $(aws ec2 describe-instances | grep InstanceId | cut -d '"' -f 4 | sort); do
    echo -n $instance
    aws ec2 describe-instance-attribute --instance-id $instance --attribute disableApiTermination | grep Value | cut -d : -f 2
done
```

Sample output from the 2nd script showing two instances, one without termination protection and one with:

```
i-0123456789abcdef0 false
i-0123456789abcdef1 true
```